# Parse date with timezone

Tags: java, android, date

I tried to parse this string :

```
"2018-08-21T10:12:06.872722+00:00"
```

but got java.text.ParseException.

I'm using this format :

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz"
```

**important: I tried to use: XXX, ZZZZZ, ZZZ, z for timezone, but not working**

What is wrong? thanks.

covert date to new format:

```
formatDate("2018-08-21T10:12:06.872722+00:00");

public static String formatDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date d;
    try {
        d = sdf.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

    return output.format(d);
}
```

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: @VivekMishra, i tried solutions from your topic, it's not work

Comment: @Abhishek, i updated my question :)

Comment: @SWR i've given an answer. Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this method.

```
void checkDateParsing()
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ");
            Date d = null;
            try {
                d = sdf.parse("2018-08-21T10:12:06.872722+00:00");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("date",d.toGMTString());
        }
```

Comment: It's working fine with your date.

Comment: ahh)) thanks for answer, i found mistake, that i use SSS instead of SSSSSS, xd, your answer is true, it's working fine now

Comment: Please vote if you find it correct.

Comment: While it may work on Android, on my Java 8 I get `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-08-21T10:12:06.872722+00:00"`. Using `XXX` instead of `Z` I get `21 Aug 2018 10:26:38 GMT`, which is 14 minutes 32 seconds off.

Answer (score 1):

The **SimpleDateFormat** class you are using is now legacy, and should be supplemented by the java.time classes. Also it isn't thread-safe.

Therefore if you are using java 8 or above then use the below sample code::

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date = "2018-08-21T10:12:06.872222+00:00";
        LocalDateTime parsedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date, java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSz"));
        System.out.println(parsedDate.format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
}
```

If you are stuck with using SimpleDateFormat class then follow the answer by @Prateek.

Comment: No need to code your own format pattern strings since the involved formats are standard (ISO 8601). Just use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` for parsing and `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` for formatting. You may even parse into an `OffsetDateTime` without mentioning any formatter at all.

Answer (score 1):

In java 8 or above, you can achieve the same effect using ***one-line*** code as:

```
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-08-21T10:12:06.872722+00:00",
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME).toLocalDate());
```

Output:

```
2018-08-21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {            
    System.out.println(formatDate("2018-08-21-10:12:06.872+0100"));

} 


public static String formatDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date d;
try {
    d = sdf.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "";
}
return output.format(d);
```

}